# Dynamic module loading not working on Firefox - SyntaxError: dynamic module import is not implemented

Tags: javascript, firefox, dynamic, module

I try to [dynamically load a module](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) on Firefox (version 66.0.2 (64 bits) on OS X 10.14.3) without success.

I get the following error:

> SyntaxError: dynamic module import is not implemented

It works fine on Google Chrome.

`index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Dynamic module test</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Test</p>
        <script async="" type="module" src="module.js"></script>
        <script type="module" src="main.js" ></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

`main.js`:

```
let main = ()=> {

    import('./module.js').then((loadedModule) => {

            console.log('module loaded')

            if(loadedModule.activate) {
                loadedModule.activate()
            }

        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error)
        });
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", main)
```

`module.js`:

```
export function activate() {
    console.log('activate module')
}
```

I made [a sample project](https://codesandbox.io/s/8n6416p8r8) that you can download export to .zip (File > Export to ZIP).

Since I had no answer so far, I made a [bug report on bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1542125).

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox/Releases/67#JavaScript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Firefox, you can change preferences in [about:config](http://about:config) to load dynamic modules:

```
  javascript.options.dynamicImport
```

As noted in comments, FF 67+ should address this problem.  It also works with no changes if you use Firefox Developer Edition.